# Curious question involving Prime Ideal and a Matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have been struggling to solve this question involving a prime ideal and a matrix:

Suppose $S$ is a commutative ring with $1$, $(a)$ is the principal ideal generated by $a\in S$ and let $P$ be a prime ideal of $S$ **properly contained** in $(a)$.

Further suppose $P=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ for some $a_1, \dots, a_n\in P$.

**Fact** (I managed to prove this): There exists a matrix $A=(b_{ij})\in M_n(S)$ such that for all $i\leq i\neq j\leq n$, $b_{ii}=1-ax_{ii}$ and $b_{ij}=ax_{ij}$ such that $$A\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

> **Question)** Using the above fact, how do we show that there exists $b\in S$ such that $(1-ab)P=0$?

I am not sure if the above requires any theorem in ring theory / linear algebra, or just elementary methods. I tried looking at small values of $n$, but could only prove it for $n=1$.

$n=1$ is trivial since $(1-ax_{11})a_1=0$, so we may take $b=x_{11}$.

For $n=2$, we get two equations:

$\begin{align*}
(1-ax_{11})a_1+(ax_{12})a_2&=0\\
(ax_{21})a_1+(1-ax_{22})a_2&=0
\end{align*}$

It is not immediately obvious to me what to take as $b$.

I also made the observation that 
$$A\begin{pmatrix}a_1r_1\\a_2r_2\\\vdots\\a_nr_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
using the fact that diagonal matrices commute with any other square matrix.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to multiply on the left by $A^*$, the classical adjoint of $A$? (This is called "the determinant trick" and has appeared for few times on M.SE.)

Comment: @user26857 Hmm no I haven't tried that. Thanks  will look into it.